# Generalized Complex Exponentiation

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Is there a way to create a general formula for exponentiating two complex numbers like there is for addition and multiplication?
Ex:

$(a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i $

$(a + bi) * (c + di) = (a * c - b * d) + (a * d + b * c)i$

$(a + bi) ^ {(c + di)} = ?$

Comment: It is definable, but has subtleties and involves the definition of a logarithm of complex numbers. It would take too long to cover as an answer here I think. Look up any textbook on "Theory of a Complex Variable" or look for lecture notes.

Comment: Is the answer too long, or is the explanation too long. If just the answer is posted I can probably figure it out, looking up what you suggested.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Comment: There is no single useful formula, it very much depends on what the complex numbers are in evaluating $z^w$. If w is an integer, the answer is as you would expect. If w is rational (a real fraction) you are into roots of complex numbers, which involves polar form and multiple roots of trigonometrical functions. Looking up 'DeMoivre's Theorem' will deal with these cases. If w is complex more machinery is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a+bi)^{(c+di)}=e^{(c+di)\ln(a+bi)}$

and

$\ln(a+bi)=\ln\left | a+bi \right |+i\arg(a+bi)$

and

$e^{m+ni}=e^m(\cos(n)+i\sin(n)).$